# Set scrollviewer control upon ellipse

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I need to set scrollviewer on ellipse. My code is :

```
<Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="301" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="http://cfile3.uf.tistory.com/image/26616E4D514A3CDC136C4B"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

i want this:

```
<scrollviewewr>
<Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="301" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="http://cfile3.uf.tistory.com/image/26616E4D514A3CDC136C4B"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse></scrollviewr>
```

But it doesn't work. when i zoom my elliptical image, it becomes rectangle.I need to zoom it with ellipse shape.Can anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Your code is missing :)

Comment: Now please check and help.

Comment: Can anyone please help me i am waiting,and its very urgent for me to do.

Comment: So you dont actually want it to scroll, you want to the mouse wheel to scale the size of the ellipse larger or smaller, is that correct?

Comment: yes, like zooming effect.

Comment: Ya, that's not what you would expect a `ScrollViewer` to do.